# How to apply blur effect to 2D textures using shaders?

Tags: shaders, monogame

I'm making a 2D game in Monogame and I'd like to learn how to apply the blur effect for layers that are "out of focus" in the deep background or very close in the foreground using shaders.

By manipulating the bitmap array of a Texture2D (it's pretty slow), I figured it would be better to draw each layer onto its own Texture2D and blur the whole thing instead of blurring individual textures. But then I learned there are shaders which are supposed to make this much faster. I've never used shaders for anything yet. How would I use shaders for the blur effect?

Most of the shader tutorials for monogame/xna I've seen so far deal only with 3D or do something I don't understand in 2D which doesn't seem to do the blur effect.

---

Following DMGregory's suggestion in the comments, I decided to try the second shader which is:

```
// Pixel shader applies a one dimensional gaussian blur filter.
// This is used twice by the bloom postprocess, first to
// blur horizontally, and then again to blur vertically.

sampler TextureSampler : register(s0);

#define SAMPLE_COUNT 15

float2 SampleOffsets[SAMPLE_COUNT];
float SampleWeights[SAMPLE_COUNT];


float4 PixelShaderF(float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
    float4 c = 0;

    // Combine a number of weighted image filter taps.
    for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLE_COUNT; i++)
    {
        c += tex2D(TextureSampler, texCoord + SampleOffsets[i]) * SampleWeights[i];
    }

    return c;
}


technique GaussianBlur
{
    pass Pass1
    {
#if SM4
        PixelShader = compile ps_4_0_level_9_1 PixelShaderF();
#elif SM3
        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 PixelShaderF();
#else
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderF();
#endif
    }
}
```

Populating it with some random floats and Vector2s in the range from 0 to 1, then 0 to 100, then -100 to 100 and it just doesn't produce any effect. I tried moving the line `blurEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();` before and after all the drawing methods and in-between, but nothing happens.

I had trouble loading it at first but then I figured it out with the content folder thing, so that doesn't seem to be the issue, or else it would probably throw an exception on the loading methods.

I've seen the exception for setting the effect parameters  incorrectly, so seems like I'm doing that right too. I think the problem might be with the values themselves. I don't know what I'm supposed to use there and why the 15 samples and not some other number.

Ideally I would like a complete noob guide to shaders on this one example of gaussian blur applied to everything (or only to certain background textures).

Comment: I found [two](http://www.software7.com/blog/monogame-hlsl-shader-example-for-a-post-processing-blur-effect/) promising-looking [leads](https://github.com/CartBlanche/MonoGame-Samples/blob/master/SamplesContentBuilder/SamplesContentBuilderContent/Effects/GaussianBlur.fx) in just the top five Google search results for "monogame blur." Try checking those out, and if you need further help, try editing your question to describe in more detail what you have so far and what step you need help with.

Comment: The first one looks bogus, and the second one is explicitly named "gaussian blur" and that's what I want, so I went for that one. I think I managed to compile and load it but it does nothing. Now I'm looking into why that could be and can't find an obvious answer. Most topics I find deal with specific target textures, and knowing nothing about how shaders work I'm thinking the second one's raw code might be missing something. It might not me as simple as adding an `effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();`

Comment: I presume you populated the sample offsets and sample weights arrays, respectively? For specific help debugging your implementation, it would be good to edit your question to include more details describing what you're doing so far.

Comment: I found how to populate the values but I'm not getting any visible effect. Are there specific numbers I should use? Why is the sample count 15 in that example? I'm seeing some shaders use a "texture" value/parameter and this one doesn't have one, so I've still got additional questions, but the biggest question remains − how to make it work.

Comment: You said you wanted a Gaussian blur, so is it safe to assume you're familiar with [Gaussian filter kernels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsU96.gif)? Since 15 isn't a square number, it looks like that particular shader is set up to do a two-pass blur, 15 taps horizontally in one pass, 15 vertically in the other. You can get the weights from the 15th row of Pascal's triangle, [as described in this article](http://rastergrid.com/blog/2010/09/efficient-gaussian-blur-with-linear-sampling/).

Comment: First time hearing about many things here, my friend. I don't know very much about 3D and effects, and I know nothing about shaders whatsoever. I just heard that's how people do blur, so that's what I picked. Gaussian blur seemed like the "good" kind of blur, and the first link you posted has a pretty crappy example, so I don't think that's what I want.